# Samsung monitor brightness changes frequently when I use it as MacBook external screen

Tags: display, multiple-monitors, macbook, macbook-pro, external-display

I've connected a Samsung s24r650 monitor via its default HDMI cable to a MacBook Pro M3 but as you see in the gif below, the brightness changes frequently (flickers). I already changed all display settings, color profiles and too many things but it still has the same issue.

Current display setting:

- resolution 1920 x 1080
- color profile: generic RGB
- refresh rate: 75 Hertz
- monitor brightness setting: standard

Please check link below:

[This is the problem with this monitor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/idIZU.gif)

Is the cable causing this problem? I think it happens only for dark colors or backgrounds.

Comment: I see flickering, but that could be from the low resolution/color gif...

Comment: @Keltari indeed, I had to compress gif file then upload here therefore it shows deformed... I've selected high-resolution (default) in display settings